# Python-docx how do I delete a table column?

Tags: python, python-docx

I need to delete a column of a table in a docx using python 3.

Nothing in internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document('YOUR_DOCX')

def Delete_column_in_table(table, columns):
    table = document.tables[table]
    grid = table._tbl.find("w:tblGrid", table._tbl.nsmap)
    for cell in table.column_cells(columns):
        cell._tc.getparent().remove(cell._tc)
    col_elem = grid[columns]
    grid.remove(col_elem)

Delete_column_in_table(0, 0)

document.save('OUT.docx')
```